# Having problems with the output of a basic script

Tags: bash

I copied that code to make a THM exercise, I understand it and it does his job that's passing names from a wordlist ($2) to steghide to try to crack the image ($1), and it works, but the problem is that it doesn't show correctly the correct password, it just stops in the word before it, and if you click enter it keeps going, I would like to just stop when it finds it and show me the password, here's the code:

```
for word in $(cat $2); do
    steghide extract -sf $1 -p $word &> /dev/null
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then
        echo
        echo "[!] PWD FOUND - $word [!]"
        break
    else
        echo "NOPE - $word"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Are there spaces in the passphrases? Your loop will split them into separate words.

Comment: Reading your wordlist with `for ... in` will probably mangle it. See ["Why you don't read lines with `for`"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [BashFAQ #1: "How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) Also, you have several variable references that really should be double-quoted; [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will point them out (along with some other recommendations).

Comment: @Pol Porta - What do you mean by _you click enter_?

Comment: @Armali I mean the return key

Comment: @Barmar It's just a regular wordlist file without any space in any word

Comment: Why do you need to press return? There's nothing in your loop that waits for input. Unless `steghide` does that itself.

Comment: I can't see any reason why it would be stopping on the word before the found password.

Comment: @Barmar I don't need to press it, but the script stops before the good password, and if I click the return key it just adds an empty line and keep trying with the rest

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script to see a trace of its activity.

Comment: There's nothing in your script that waits for any keyboard input. It should run to completion all by itself without you pressing return.

Comment: @Barmar I have just realised that I can press any button, it'll just add it and follow with the program, so if I add an space it will just show the space, the correct password but with the tag NOPE and keep going, so it never shows me the good one as PWD FOUND

Comment: @Barmar I did it, and i realised that all the passwords give me 1 = 0, so error, but it stops before the good one

Comment: @Barmar even the good one gives me 1 == 0

Comment: Can you run `steghide extract` by hand with the correct password? What does `echo $?` after that show?

Comment: If it always says 1 == 0, it shouldn't stop until it gets to the end of the word list. Unless `steghide` is waiting for you to type something.

Comment: Try adding `</dev/null` to the `steghide` line.

Comment: @Barmar okay, I just feel so stupid right now, as I already extracted the file from the image once, steghide was asking me if i wanted to re-write the file, so that was the whole problem, I'm still a newbie, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: BTW, `foo; if [ $? == 0 ]; then` is an antipattern -- it's always better to write `if foo; then` which has the same effect and fewer bugs (among those bugs, not all versions of `[` allow `==` at all, since the POSIX standard only specifies `=` as a string comparison operator).

Comment: (Another of those bugs is that if `set -e` is set, the script will always immediately exit if your `foo` has a nonzero exit status, making the `else` branch of your `if` unreachable -- the `set -e` behavior has special-case handling for "checked" exits inside conditionals, but when you run `foo` -- or `steghide` -- as its own command, that special-case handling isn't reached).

Answer (score 1):

Steghide was asking me if I wanted to re-write the output file as I already did this process once, so that was the only problem, my script wasn't expecting another input request from steghide.